# sobolev spaces - product of two functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I am working in a exercise, to my solution works I need the following affirmation is true:

Let $\varphi : R \rightarrow R$ a convex and smooth function. Let $u \in H^{1}(U)$ a bounded function and $v \in H^{1}_{0}(U)$ a non negative function. Then $\varphi^{'}(u)v \in H^{1}_{0}(U)$.

I am trying to use the definiton , but it's not working. Someone can give me a hint?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Doubly posted: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398743/sobolev-spaces-about-weak-derivative

Answer (score 1):

You need some more assumptions. Let us consider the simple case $\varphi(x) = x^2$, then $\varphi'(x) = x$. You want to have $u \, v \in H^1(\Omega)$ for $u, v \in H^1(\Omega)$. Using the product rule one can show that the weak derivative of the product is $\nabla (u \, v) = u \, \nabla v + v \, \nabla u$. However, this function may not belong to $L^2(\Omega)$. You may want to assume $u, v \in H^1(\Omega) \cap L^\infty(\Omega)$.

Comment: hmmmm thanks. my question arises from this exercise of EVans (  the PDE book). the exercise is here http://books.google.com.br/books?id=Xnu0o_EJrCQC&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR#v=onepage&q&f=false  .  exercise 11 page 367 . I was trying to solve the question in the natural way ( doing the calculus with no preocupation) and then arises my question ...

Comment: Why do you want to show that $\varphi'(u) \, v \in H^1(\Omega)$. You only need that $\varphi(u) \in H^1(\Omega)$ and by the chain rule you get $\nabla(\varphi(u)) = \varphi'(u)\,\nabla u \in L^2(\Omega)$.