# Sobolev spaces - about weak derivative

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $U$ a bounded and open subset of $R^n$. Let $u \in  H^{1}(U)$ a bounded function , $v \in H^{1}_{0}(U)$ a non negative function. Consider $\varphi : R \rightarrow R$ a convex and smooth function.Is true that $\varphi^{'}(u)v \in H^{1}_{0}(U)$?

I am trying , but nothing works... Someone can give me a  hint ?

Comment: Doubly posted: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398686/sobolev-spaces-product-of-two-functions